# Adding an ScriptReference Dynamically which is a page request to ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager, dynamic

I use ScriptManager in my ASP.NET page, and want to add a ScriptReference which is a page request like this:

```
var id = 10;
tsm.CompositeScript.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference("~/Response.aspx?action=test&id=" + id));
```

but it raises an error:

> ```
> '~/Response.aspx?action=test&id=10' is not a valid virtual path.
> ```

I should add this script dynamically, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to mix a virtual path with `querystring` parameters, I think the underlying ASP.NET method that resolves the "`~`" part expects the string to be a pure virtual path, not a url.
So, map it as a pure path first, and then add the query:

```
 tsm.CompositeScript.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference(ResolveClientUrl("~/Response.aspx") + "?action=test&id=" + id));
```